# Java: invocar método público de una clase

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de la cual trata de unos clientes de un banco, tengo la clase Cliente que  representa los clientes del banco antes mencionado:

```
public class Cliente {

    private String nombre;
    private CuentaBancaria cuenta; //Aqui se está creado

    //Constructor
    public Cliente(String nombre, CuentaBancaria cuenta) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cuenta = cuenta;

    }

    public void obtenerDatosDeCuenta() {
        cuenta = new CuentaBancaria("123456-7", (float) 10500.75);
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("Juan Perez", cuenta);
        System.out.println("Que pedo" + cliente);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Aqui ya no se que show XD
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public CuentaBancaria getCuenta() {
        return cuenta;
    }

    public void setCuenta(CuentaBancaria cuenta) {
        this.cuenta = cuenta;
    }

}
```

Y esta clase llamada CuentaBancaria:

```
public class CuentaBancaria {

    private String numero;
    private float saldo;

    public CuentaBancaria(String numero, float saldo) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public float getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(float saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    

}
```

El problema es que no se como mandar a llamar el metodo obtenerDatosDeCuenta() ya que dicho metodo no lo puedo mandar a llamar desde el main ya que marca error de que no se puede ser referenciado de un contexto estatico.

El problema como tal es todo esto que ya casi lo tengo solo que este problema no me deja continuar:

```
2.  Tenemos una clase Cliente, la cual representa a todos los clientes de un banco. Se observa que la clase Cliente va a tener un atributo de tipo CuentaBancaria. La clase CuentaBancaria va a tener los siguientes atributos:
a.  numero, de tipo String y private.
b.  saldo, de tipo float y private.
Dentro de la clase Cliente, debe haber un atributo de tipo String llamado nombre y un atributo cuenta de tipo CuentaBancaria. Al inicializar el atributo de instancia cuenta de tipo CuentaBancaria, debe ser de la siguiente manera, por ejemplo:
cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(“123456-7”, 10500.75);
En la misma clase Cliente, debe haber un método de instancia llamado obtenerDatosDeCuenta() que debe imprimir el número de la cuenta y el saldo que tiene hasta ese momento. El constructor de la clase Cliente será de la siguiente manera:
public Cliente(String nombre, CuentaBancaria cuenta)
{
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.cuenta = cuenta;
}
De tal manera que en el método main() de la clase Cliente vamos a crear un objeto de tipo Cliente. Al crear un objeto de tipo Cliente, previamente debe crearse un objeto de tipo cuenta (porque debe pasarse al constructor de la clase Cliente) para que se haga de la siguiente manera:
cuenta = new CuentaBancaria(“123456-7”, 10500.75);
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(“Juan Perez”, cuenta);
Y a partir de esta referencia llamada cliente, debe invocarse al método obtenerDatosDeCuenta() para observar los datos propios del objeto cuenta.
```

El error como tal es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> non-static method obtenerDatosDeCuenta() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Si el problema es que no sabes, la solución es que aprendas. No tenemos forma de ayudarte si no pones tu mensaje de error, es más, tu código está en modo librería, así que tampoco sabemos de que forma lo ejecutas.

Comment: Hola amigo, el error como tal es este: non-static method obtenerDatosDeCuenta() cannot be referenced from a static context, quiero mandar a llamar la información que trae ese metodo pero por ser estatico no me deja ya que no permite invocar metodo de referencia el main ya que es estatico :(

Comment: Ya edité mi publicación espero y me comprendan, quedo al pendiente, saludos

Answer (score 3):

Creo que debes de crear tu objeto Cliente en el main y luego llamar el método

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria("123456-7", (float) 10500.75);
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("Juan Perez", cuenta);

        cliente.obtenerDatosDeCuenta();
    }
```

Y tu método obtenerDatosDeCuenta() quedaría algo así

```
    public void obtenerDatosDeCuenta() {          
        System.out.println("Que pedo " + this.nombre);
        System.out.println("CUENTA");
        System.out.println("Número: " + this.getCuenta().getNumero());
        System.out.println("Saldo: " + this.getCuenta().getSaldo());
    }
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo ya quedó, con esta respuesta funcionó muchas gracias Oscar y a todos por su ayuda. Saludos a todos :)

Comment: @cratus666jose Si esta respuesta fue la que te solucionó el problema, por favor considera marcarla como aceptada. Igualmente, si otras resupuestas te ayudaron cosidera votarlas positivo.

Comment: Hola, como hago eso? Ya hice lo de clickear la flecha hacia, no sé si sea solo con eso XD

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que no se pude llamar métodos públicos desde métodos estáticos. En el libro Introducción a la programción con Java de Jhon Dean y Raymon Dean te recomiendan poner el método main en un clase diferente, y a partir de aquí instanciar las variables y llamar al método obtenerDatosDeCuenta(). Por ejemplo podrías crear una clase llamada Banco, en esa clase puedes incluir al método main como su único método, donde instancies un objeto cliente y llames al método obtenerDatosDeCuenta(), entonces dentro de esa clase, almacenarías la clase Cliente como una clase privada, ya que no pueden haber dos clases públicas en un mismo achivo java:

Banco.java

```
public class Banco{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cuenta = new CuentaBancaria("123456-7", (float) 10500.75);
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("Juan Perez", cuenta);
        cliente.obtenerDatosDeCuenta();
    }

    private class Cliente {
        private String nombre;
        private CuentaBancaria cuenta; //Aqui se está creado
    
        //Constructor
        public Cliente(String nombre, CuentaBancaria cuenta) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.cuenta = cuenta;
        }
        
        public void obtenerDatosDeCuenta() {          
            System.out.println("Que pedo " + this.nombre);
            System.out.println("CUENTA");
            System.out.println("Número: " + this.getCuenta().getNumero());
            System.out.println("Saldo: " + this.getCuenta().getSaldo());
        }
        
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
        
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
        
        public CuentaBancaria getCuenta() {
            return cuenta;
        }
        
        public void setCuenta(CuentaBancaria cuenta) {
            this.cuenta = cuenta;
        }
    }
}
```

Esta solución es en conjunto con la solución de ÓscarG.

Comment: La solución de convertir el método obtenerDatosCuenta () en estático no esta mal, aunque no es recomendable ya que una de las características del lenguaje Java es el encapsulamiento, y el quizás puedan ver esa práctica mal,  aunque repito, también soluciona el problema.

Comment: Hola amigo buenas noches, esa tambien está muy padre la solución pero lo que sucede es que es un ejercicio que ya venía como tal las clases predefinidas y no crear otras, pero de antemano te agradezco por la solución,saludos y que andes chido :)

Answer (score 0):

Oye, prueba colocando el metodo obtenerDatosDeCuenta como static void, ya que lo estas llamando desde un contexto estatico (public STATIC void Main) y creo que solo puedes llamar metodos estáticos desde un contexto estático.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, ya lo intenté y me marca error en los que tengo del metodo ObtenerDatosCuenta(), el error es: non-static variable cuenta cannot be referenced from a static context :(

Comment: _intenta tambien colocar como estatica la funcion public STATIC CuentaBancaria_

Comment: Hola, te refieres al metodo obtenerDatosDeCuenta cuando mencionas CuentaBancaria?

Comment: _Disculpa, no me había percatado de que hay una clase con ese nombre.Prueba entonces colocando esa clase estatica.. (PUBLIC STATIC CLASS CUENTA BANCARIA). De ese modo el objeto que instancies de ella (en tu caso la variable cuenta que recibe el constructor de la clase cliente) será estatico. Y dado que tu error ahora dice que la variable cuenta no puede ser referenciada desde un contexto estatico, entonces si colocas como estatica la clase cuentaBancaria el objeto recibido tambien será de tipo estatico. En una clase estatica puedes acceder (o a mi me servía) a sus metodos así Clase::metodo_

Comment: _aunque no tienes necesidad de instanciar cuando usas una clase estatica. Así que yo probaría tambien cambiando esta linea  cuenta = new CuentaBancaria("123456-7", (float) 10500.75); pero no sé exactamente la sintaxis a seguir. Disculpa que no coloque los códigos con el formato para código que ofrece stack overflow. Estoy empezando con su uso y no se hacerlo aún jeje pero espero ayudarte_

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en leerme, la respuesta de Oscar G fue la correcta y la solución a mi problema, Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Primero has de crear un cliente:

```
Cliente c = new Client();
```

y entonces podras hacer

```
c.obtenerCuentaBancaria();
```

Comment: Hola, si hago eso no se podría ya que cuando lo crea manda a llamar mi contructor principal de la clase Cliente

Comment: Entonces haz esto:

CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria("43254323" , 0f);
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("Dani" , cuenta);

Y posteriormente:

c1.obtenerCuentaBancaria();

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de crear un cliente (Por ejemplo: cliente1) :

Cliente cliente1 = new Client();

Una vez esto, podrás realizar la llamada al método.

cliente1.obtenerCuentaBancaria();